# Salesforce DE in Journey builder and Campaign Member activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I need to use a Salesforce Data Extension in a journey builder, but Salesforce DE are no longer selectable as entry sources in JB apparently. Is there a workaround for this? I need this in order to get individual mail results.

Also, if I use the Campaign Member activity in the JB and do an update, will I get the same results as with the individual mail results?

Comment: This should not be necessary, but you can test the following:

Try to use a normal DE as entry source.
Quoting an SF document:
"Emails sent through Journey Builder will return tracking to the Sales Cloud &
Service Cloud".

To my knowledge this is because Journey Builder as a channel (in contrast to Email Studio as a different channel) supports the SF tracking feature once it recognizes the SFID in the field set in Send Relationship.

"Normal DEs" from Email Studio do not, and they need to be converted to an SFDE in order to do the same. 
Let me know if this worked :)

Comment: @jonas, you should post this as an answer instead as it is indeed the correct solution/answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a normal DE as entry source.

Quoting an SF document: "Emails sent through Journey Builder will return tracking to the Sales Cloud & Service Cloud". To my knowledge this is because Journey Builder as a channel (in contrast to Email Studio as a different channel) supports the SF tracking feature once it recognizes the SFID in the field set in Send Relationship. 
"Normal DEs" from Email Studio do not, and they need to be converted to an SFDE in order to do the same.